# Animate 2D Human body Skeletal using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to create a 2D skeletal animation using JavaScript library to make interactive 2D animations in the browser.

I'd like to create a human body. Let's consider this simple scenario to better explain what I want to achieve. I have a text box where I can enter an instruction like "say Hi", then the body should raise a hand up and give hi five. I am working to draw the both images and make them show up at every time.

- When `Init()` : I show the body (Image One)
- When I request to say Hi : I show the next body taking the hands up (Image two)

And I do animation by creating a `HTML5` canvas, the same way as: http://jsfiddle.net/FZyA3/

The problem is that I have to make more than 50 instructions. It's heavy to draw all the scenarios where I have common cases. Is there any open source character to use, like Three.js and babylon.js?

Is there any other better solution, like pixelising the arm and making it movable within an `HTML5` canvas?

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommand spine: http://esotericsoftware.com/
It's an editor which comes with an JS-runtime.

Comment: Watch the License Agreement. EVERY developer, not just the animator, needs a license. This is not compatible with OSS or small scale / hobby development.